# If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two neighborhoods of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then show that $G_1 \cap G_2$ is a neighborhood of x.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two neighborhoods of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then show that $G_1 \cap G_2$ is a neighborhood of x.

Below is a revised proposed proof following the comments received.

$G_1$ and $G_2$ neighborhoods of x implies there is are open sets $U$ and $V$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x \in U \subset G_1$ and $x \in V \subset G_2$. So $ x \in U \cap V$ and $U \cap V$ is open since it is a finite intersection of open sets. Also, $U \cap V \subset U \subset G_1$ and $U \cap V \subset V \subset G_2$. Then we have $x \in U \cap V \subset G_1 \cap G_2$. Since $U \cap V$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ then $G_1 \cap G_2$ is a neighborhood of x.

Comment: This question seems appropriate, but I would say there is an open set $U_1\subset \mathbb R$ such that $x\in U_1\subset G_1$ and an open set $U_2\subset\mathbb R$ such that $x\in U_2\subset G_2$ -- then can you find an open set $U\in G_1\cap G_2$ such that $x\in U$?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have incorporated them in the revised post above.

Comment: Your post above looks good now